# hbase hive join fails

Tags: hive, hbase

I am executing a very simple join between an hbase integrated external hive table and another hive table. I am able to query them individually but not together using a join.

```
SELECT c.rowkey 
FROM 
lookup_customerstatuslookup c   --hbase integrated external hive table
JOIN customerstatus b           -- hive table
on c.rowkey = b.customerstatuskey
```

Below is the error message displayed in hue. It doesnt even progress to map phase. 
[image]
[image: Not ending with any error message]

I dont have any clue as to how to debug it further.

Comment: Hive errors can be incredibly useless. There's no error message in the log image, is there an error in the full log?

Comment: I tested join between hbase integrated hive to hbase integrated hive table and it fails with same log as above.

Comment: @Andrew sometimes if change query a bit like select count(*) then it shows an error after that jobconf.xml line.  Execution failed with exit status 2. Obtaining error information. Task failed. Task id : stage-4.  Now this stage 4 is the very first step i see in explain plan. Nothing conclusive from this error message

Comment: for some reason map join was not working in my case. So tried disabling it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Owing to the SQL-like nature of Hive, it is simpler and a lot easier to frame our jobs with stored structured data, thus justifying its extensive use in Hadoop. While that being true, another fact merits attention: When there are large data-sets in Hive joins, a frequent predicament faced is the errors resulting from out of memory or java heap space.

**Increase the heap size**

After having included the map-join and/or the EQUI join, one of things you may want to look at is increasing the heap size of the child tasks of MapReduce.
You can do so by setting the property ‘mapred.child.java.opts’ to a higher value. For example, to increase the heap size to 1GB, set it as

```
mapred.child.java.opts=  -Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the issue was not related to the memory in my case. Both tables had less than 1k rows so the optimizer was opting for a map join. Somehow map joins were failing when a hbase integrated hive table was introduced to the join. I took up the issue with Cloudera and they suggested to disable map side join.